# 7k | $(10^{7k} -1)$

Tags: combinatorics

I look for a $k$ such that $7k$ divides $10^{7k} -1$. I am pretty sure such a $k$ does not exist, because the 7 is not a term of OEIS A066364, but how could I prove that?

I realized that all terms of A014950 have an odd multiplicative order 10, whereas multiples of 7 have an even multiplicative order 10. But then I am stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We remark that the order of $10\pmod 7$ is $6$. But if $10^{7k}\equiv 1\pmod {7k}$ then $10^{7k}\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ which implies that $6\,|\,7k$.   But then $7k$ must be even, in which case $7k$ can not divide the odd number $10^{7k}-1$.